# What part of C++ creates many "copies" of objects?

Tags: c++

Although I develop C++ primarily, I don't get the joke about C++ down there. Is this joke about passing by value being default behavior, and hence creating many copies? Or is there some other part of C++ that created this reputation?

[image]

Comment: The funny thing also is HTML is the only language you can actually write an essay in.

Comment: I think this has more to do with C++'s reputation of being quite verbose and less expressive compared to other languages.

Comment: My guess is the commonality of interspersed `#ifdef ... #ifndef ...` along with platform-specific identifiers in order to write an inline "version" for every platform.

Comment: I guess if you're not careful and know what you're doing you create many copies in C++ when you return an object by a function, pass it by value or just assign it to another variable etc.. :D

Comment: @xander That's the only part that makes sense to me, but I'm wondering whether there's something else, as I'm not sure the joke is made for "bad programmers", but for the nature of the language.

Comment: You need to provide a reference for where you obtained this image, in order to adhere to the website rules.

Comment: Prior to C++11, returning an object from a function conceptually involved a minimum of 3 copies

Comment: ... And if 3 copies doesn't seem that bad, imagine it's a vector of 1 million records... yeah.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Where you are getting this kind of jokes?

Comment: "Prior to C++11, returning an object from a function conceptually involved a minimum of 3 copies" - well sometimes RVO could help. Also the joke may address the tons of classes generated by code that extensively uses templates

Comment: You already basically answered your own question, so I'm not sure what's left for us to do. "Explain this joke" seems like it should be off topic, and explaining all the way C++ can potentially create "unnecessary" copies of things seems too broad.

Comment: Also, it's opinion-based, since you're asking about C++'s "reputation", which everyone may not agree exists, and there may be different opinions about how C++ came to have this reputation.

Comment: @nakiya ... less expressive? I guess that's where "opinion-based" comes from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compared to other OO languages, C++ heavily uses value semantics. Code like `Object B = A;` in many languages creates a new reference, but not a new Object. We call this reference semantics. In these languages, you'd have to write something like `Object B = new Object(A)` to make a copy. But with value semantics, `Object B = A;` is actually a copy.

A secondary cause was that C++ doesn't use garbage collection. This means you often needed a copy of an object, to guarantee its lifetime. (Today we have `std::shared_ptr` for that)